# More than one Ad Unit id in the same Android App

Tags: android, admob

I have an Android App on Google Play. I would like to know about the following points:

1. What is the best refresh rate for admob ads, that can earn me the most.
2. I have 3 activities in my App, and I am using the same Ad Unit id for each of them. Would I earn more if I use different Ad Unit id in each of the activities? Is it against the Admob policy, if I use more than one Ad Unit id in the same App?

Any help or guidance in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No not against the policy as far as I know. Because, I have seen this scenario before.

Comment: @Nabin: Thank you for your reply. Do you think using different Ad Unit Ids, in different activities, of the same App, would be beneficial in terms of earning money?

Comment: It's your app, your property, so I guess, it's upto you to decide what to do.

Comment: @Nabin: Of course it's upto me to decide what to do. However, I was just requesting for your suggestion.

Comment: Its not against policy. I have done it already after checking their policies.

Comment: @CodeProcessor: Thank you for your reply bro. Do you think using different Ad Unit Ids, in different activities, of the same App, would be beneficial in terms of earning money?

Comment: @user1903022 Multiple ad units vs single ad unit in several screen places in your current screen/activity/fragment depends entirely of the ad campaign bound to this ad unit. If you have more than a single ad with same ad unit in same activity, you risk to show exact same ad on more than one place. The opposite is valid too - multiple ad units with same ad campaign == same ads quite often

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What is the best refresh rate for admob ads, that can earn me the most.

Refresh time doesn't matter so much. You earn from clicking mostly. As long as ad rotation does not show same ads one after another - it is fine

> I have 3 activities in my App, and I am using the same Ad Unit id for each of them. Would I earn more if I use different Ad Unit id in each of the activities? Is it against the Admob policy, if I use more than one Ad Unit id in the same App?

Since they are separate activities, single ad unit backed with an ad campaign which does not repeat same ads - it is a good solution.

Ad units normally are for analytics/tracking. If you don't care about this - then single ad unit is fine.

Eventually you may try separate ad units - one for every activity. You can still backed them with same ad campaign (to save money :) or can use different campaigns.

And you can use multiple ad units in same activity - no agreement violation.

Comment: I always bind one ad unit to a specific screen section (activity, fragment or even a separate view container). I suggest having separate ad unit for every activity. Then try to sniff and return user location which will help personalizing ads to a point. Since you are not having campaigns, revenue difference will be minimal whatever you do :)

Comment: G: Thank you for your reply. To whom do I return the user location and how?

Comment: Please look at [setLocation(Location)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder). Then check [how to retrieve the last known location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html). There are other ways to sniff location (by IP, GPS, GeoCoder) but as a starter the links are enough. And please mark the answer as useful if you think it helped.

Comment: Sure, I am going to accept the answer. Just one more thing. After getting the user's location, how do I share this user information with the Ad Unit?

Comment: Whenever you are creating your admob `AdRequest`, using [AdRequest.Builder.setLocation(Location)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder) is the method where you are passing the location.

Comment: Also, will passing the location or any other user data make the publisher of the App earn more?

Comment: Since you are not using campaigns - no. And using campaigns cost. So for an indie dev/project - your current choice is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As a publisher, your revenue is from fill rate and CPC (or CPM).  if you run the campaigns from admob network, under CPC model, you are paid by click. You can set short refresh time, though it barely affects the number of clicks, it does have negative impact on your fill rate. Admob network engine is smart enough (like what others do) to serve those inventories with better performance first.

if you join the RTB marketplace, you probably want to separate the ad units in different activities. So you can give different meta data or attribute (for example, the ad unit is on sport content page, or on cosmetics page) to the ad units, which greatly affects the actual buyer's bidding price. As a publisher, if u want maximise the revenue, try pass some user information to the ad unit, such as geo location if any, or gender etc... impressions with data make huge difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply bro. Could you please suggest how do I pass some user information to the Ad Unit?